# Bounds for samples from the normal distribution using numpy.random.randn

Tags: normal-distribution, numpy

I am new to both stats and scientific Python, so apologies if this question breaches any guidelines.

I want to know what `x = np.random.randn(500)` actually does, in terms I can understand. Why exactly does plotting x give values in the range shown in this image:

[image]

?

It looks like the values range roughly from -3 to 3, yet I can find no mention of the range in documentation for `numpy.random.randn`. Therefore I'm assuming this property must somehow be intrinsic to a standard normal distribution, but I don't have enough knowledge of this entity to understand why.

Is it possible, although wildly improbable, that values with a much greater magnitude could be generated? Is it a feature of the specific implementation that the values range from -3 to +3 ish, rather than, say, -10 to +10 ish?

Comment: `randn` simply generates pseudo-random numbers from the **standard normal distribution** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution). The values are unbound, but very large and very small values are highly improbable.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, it is possible but wildly improbable. Theoretically, any value is possible but 99.7% of standard normal random variables are between -3 and +3. Only 1 in a billion will be larger than 6 (or less than -6).

Comment: I'm still a bit confused though. Why is the range not -30 to +30 or -300 to +300? How does the standard normal distribution "know" what range comprises 1,2 or 3 standard deviations, when no actual values are specified?

Comment: That's what a distribution does. It specifies precisely the probability that X can be less than -3, greater than 4, etc. This particular distribution just has the property that almost all values are between -3 and 3.  There are other distributions that can have large values. For example, normal with mean 0 and variance 100. Now, most of the values will be between -30 and 30 and you will often see numbers like 10.5583, -21.444421, etc.

Comment: So there is an implicit variance of 10 in the values produced by the function?

Comment: No: by definition, the variance is $1.$